# What time of day do Heroku dynos get restarted?

Tags: heroku

I know that Heroku auto-restarts dynos once a day. Are they restarted around the same time each day? Or just 24 hours from when they were first started?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Around, but not necessarily precisely, 24h after boot.

Also, potentially any time before that if load needs to be redistributed.